# How to route URL with dash in sub folder in FuelPHP?

Tags: php, routes, fuelphp

I have URL: `http://localhost/dir-withdash/controller`

And this is folder structure.

```
/fuel
..../app
......../classes
............/controller
................/dir-withdash
..................../controller.php
............/model
............/view
```

the controller file is in /fuel/app/classes/controller/dir-withdash/controller.php

The problem is..

How to named the controller class? and How to route to his controller?

---

This is my controller class which is not work.

```
class Controller_DirWithdash_Index extends \Controller 
{


    public function action_index() 
    {

    }// action_index


}
```

This is my route which is not work too.

```
'dir-withdash/(.*)' => 'DirWithdash/$1',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the aim is to have a hyphen in the URL, I would suggest that you remove the hyphen in the folder:

`/fuel/app/classes/controller/DirWithdash/Home.php`

Update the routes file to the following, where `home` points to your controller, and `index` is your action:

`'dir-withdash/(.*)' => 'DirWithdash/Home/index/$1',`

And update your class to the following:

```
class Controller_DirWithdash_Home extends \Controller 
{

    public function action_index() 
    {

    }// action_index

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to contain "-" in the folder? because my old project (CI framework) has those folder with "-".

Comment: Fuel will look for a class name of `Controller_Dir-Withdash_Home`, which is an invalid class name in PHP, so you will have to use the routing to translate this correctly. You might want to look at if you can change uri to something more sensible.